# Cannot include header from boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem using - including boost library.

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
```

And I'm getting error: boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp: No such file or directory
I have a boost folder inside where my project is... *How to fix it* ? Thanks

Comment: Are you using an IDE, or Makefiles or cmake ? Usually the error message indicates that the compiler can't find the directory where the  header files are.

Comment: before you can use <...> you have to add the boost path to your project. I would recommend you to download boostPro, install it and then add the boostPro path to your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `boost` folder inside your project, you may just need to tell the compiler to look into that folder for header files.

With gcc/g++ this can be done with the `-I</path/to/headers>` option (without angular parentheses).

Other compilers work the same way with possibly different flags than `-I`.